# Left align after \specialcell in a centered table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I'm outputting descriptive tables from Stata using `estpost` and `esttab` into TeX format, and then importing them in LyX. I use `\refcat` to label my survey questions, and since some of them are very long I need to put linebreaks using `\specialcell` (I already do this in Stata). However, these seem to center automatically, which turns out ugly. Can I adjust my Stata code to have my labels (`\refcats`) align left?

This is my Stata code (updated after comment):

```
local opin_padres P64_rev_1_lf-P65_rev_5_lf P74_rev_1_lf-P75_rev_5_lf

estpost su `opin_padres' if tratamiento==0
est store P1

estpost su `opin_padres' if tratamiento==1
est store P2

estpost su `opin_padres' 
est store P3

esttab P1 P2 P3 using `opinpadres', replace longtable booktabs addnotes(Todos las variables han sido ponderadas en porcentajes (\%)) ///
    refcat(P64_rev_1_lf "\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{El rendimiento de los alumnos depende en gran parte de su\\situaci\'on familiar}}\\" ///
    P65_rev_1_lf "\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{La educaci\'on es una prioridad para los\\padres de los alumnos de su secci\'on}}\\" ///
    P74_rev_1_lf "\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{C\'omo es su relaci\'on con los padres de alumnos?}}\\" ///
    P75_rev_1_lf "\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{C\'omo es su relaci\'on con la comunidad en la que se encuentra la escuela?}}\\", nolabel) ///
    mtitle("Control" "Tratamiento" "\textbf{Total}") cells(mean(fmt(1))) label nonum collabels(none) noobs
```

And this the TeX code of the table:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{longtable}{l*{3}{c}}
\toprule\endfirsthead\midrule\endhead\midrule\endfoot\endlastfoot
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Control}&\multicolumn{1}{c}   {Tratamiento}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Total}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{El rendimiento de los alumnos depende en gran parte de su\\situaci\'on familiar}}&            &            &            \\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy de acuerdo&        39.1&        34.3&        36.6\\
\hspace{0.2cm}De acuerdo&        51.6&        50.7&        51.1\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Indiferente&         0.0&         4.5&         2.3\\
\hspace{0.2cm}En desacuerdo&         9.4&        10.4&         9.9\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy en desacuerdo&         0.0&         0.0&         0.0\\
\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{La educaci\'on es una prioridad para los\\padres de los alumnos de su secci\'on}}&            &            &            \\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy de acuerdo&        18.8&        10.4&        14.5\\
\hspace{0.2cm}De acuerdo&        45.3&        50.7&        48.1\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Indiferente&        18.8&        22.4&        20.6\\
\hspace{0.2cm}En desacuerdo&        12.5&        11.9&        12.2\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy en desacuerdo&         4.7&         4.5&         4.6\\
\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{C\'omo es su relaci\'on con los padres de alumnos?}}&            &            &            \\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy buena&        31.2&        21.5&        26.4\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Buena &        54.7&        69.2&        62.0\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Regular&        14.1&         9.2&        11.6\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Mala  &         0.0&         0.0&         0.0\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy mala&         0.0&         0.0&         0.0\\
\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{C\'omo es su relaci\'on con la comunidad en la que se encuentra la escuela?}}\\&            &            &            \\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy buena&        23.4&        10.9&        17.2\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Buena &        68.8&        79.7&        74.2\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Regular&         7.8&         9.4&         8.6\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Mala  &         0.0&         0.0&         0.0\\
\hspace{0.2cm}Muy mala&         0.0&         0.0&         0.0\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Todos las variables han sido ponderadas en porcentajes (\%)}\\
\end{longtable}
}
```

This is the latest version of my preamble:

```
% Packages for tables
\usepackage{booktabs}% Pretty tables
\usepackage{threeparttablex}% For Notes below table
\usepackage{longtable}%Long tables

% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}} % Thanks to Joseph Wright & David Carlisle

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    group-digits            = false,
    input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
    table-align-text-post   = false,
    input-signs             = ,
    }   

% Character substitution that prints brackets and the minus symbol in text mode. Thanks to   David Carlisle
\def\yyy{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\llap{\textendash}\relax}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }

\def\xxxl#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\llap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\xxxr#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\rlap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\textsymbols{\xxxl[\xxxr]\xxxl(\xxxr)\yyy}


% *****************************************************************
% Estout related things
% *****************************************************************
\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
    \vspace{.75ex}{
        \textsymbols% Note the added command here
        \begin{tabular*}
        {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
        \toprule
        \estinput{#1}
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[.75ex]
        \end{tabular*}
        }
    }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
    \vspace{.75ex}{
        \textsymbols% Note the added command here
        \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
        \toprule
        \estinput{#1}
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[.75ex]
        \end{tabular}
        }
    }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}
                   %%%
}

% *****************************************************************
% Custom subcaptions
% *****************************************************************
% Note/Source/Text after Tables
% The new approach using threeparttables to generate notes that are the exact width of the table.
\newcommand{\Figtext}[1]{%
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
\hspace{6pt}
\hangindent=1.75em
#1
\end{tablenotes}
}
\newcommand{\Fignote}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\Figsource}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}
\newcommand{\Starnote}{\Figtext{\textit{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01.}\\  Errores est\'andares corregidos por correlaci\'on y heteroskedasticidad a nivel de escuela entre par\'entesis.}}% Add significance note with \starnote
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, please edit the code to be a complete document starting `\documentclass` in particular, what package are you using that defines `\specialcell` which isn't a standard command. I t can probably be redefined to be left aligned but it would be easier to redefine if you showed the original definition.

Comment: I added my preamble

Comment: Also do you want those long entries just in the first column or could they span the whole table?

Comment: The can span the whole table

Answer (score 4):

Your command

```
% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}
```

defines centred entries, you can change it to define left aligned

```
% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}% missing % in original
                       %%%
}
```

Rather than force things into the first column you could replace

```
\textbf{\specialcell{C\'omo es su relaci\'on con la comunidad\\en la que se encuentra la escuela?}}&            &            &            \\
```

by

```
\multicolumn{4}{\textbf{\specialcell{C\'omo es su relaci\'on con la comunidad\\en la que se encuentra la escuela?}}\\
```

If your generator can make spanning entries?

Comment: The left aligning works now (thanks a lot!), but spanning the label across multiple columns still not. Possible still some bug in my preamble? I updated my Stata code, latex output and preamble above.

Comment: Your generator is still putting `& & &` ie three blank entries after the 4 entry span so that makes a row with 7 entries instead of 4. You need to suppress them: I can't help with the `stata` code (I have never heard of that language:-)

Comment: Hmm yes I see, I don't manage to suppress them as Stata automatically generates these columns to output results. I probably have to append different tables after each other to be able to span the labels. I'm going to play around a bit with it, thanks!!